# backbone marionette incorrect rendering of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, marionette

I'm working on implementing a QR reader in a web based app that uses the PC's webcam. This is currently working correct.

The framework that I use ([barcode.js](https://github.com/Schibum/barcode.js)) has a function render(element).

I have 2 different files, ScannerView.html and ScannerView.js. See their code below:

**ScannerView.html**

```
<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<section class="content-header has-background-image">
<div class="background">
    <img src="/assets/temp/header.png" />
</div>
<h1><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></div> <%=name%></h1>
</section>

<section class="content">
    // Withing the following div, the canvas element should be placed
    <div id="scanner"></div>
</section>
```

**ScannerView.js**

```
var YookrApp = require("../../setup");
var scanner = null;

var ScannerView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: require("./ScannerView.html"),
  className: "scannerView",

  ui: {
    scannerDiv: "#scanner"
  },

  name: "Yookr Code Scanner",

  initialize: function(options) {
  },

  onRender: function() {
    w69b.qr.decoding.setWorkerUrl("assets/w69b.qrcode.decodeworker.js");
    scanner =  new w69b.qr.ui.ContinuousScanner();
    // Called when a qr code has been decoded.
    scanner.setDecodedCallback(function(result) {
        console.log("Decoded qr code:", result);
    });
    scanner.setStopped(false);
    // Render component in element with id "scanner".
    console.log("Start rendering");
    scanner.render(this.ui.scannerDiv);
    console.log("Rendering done");
  },

  close: function() {
    // We have to dispose the scanner object.
    // If we don"t do this, the webcam will
    // always be enabled
    scanner.dispose();
  }
});

module.exports = ScannerView;
```

When I run my app, the `scanner.render()` function should add a `<canvas>` element inside `<div id="scanner"></div>` in **ScannerView.html**

---

**Problem**

I'm not able to render the canvas using `scanner.render()` properly withing the `<div id="scanner"></div>` that is located in my html file. I tried to use document.getElementById and this.ui.scannerDiv with different, but not correct result.

Because I defined an UI element in the **ScannerView.js** file, I should be able to call `scanner.render(this.ui.scannerDiv);` This should use the div with id *scanner* in my html view, but instead the canvas is not rendered at all. In my console, I can see the following warnings:

> [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0000020AB57365B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: framebuffer incomplete

and

> [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0000020AB57365B0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 2 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.

When I use `scanner.render(document.getElementById("scanner"));`, I can see that the canvas is rendered, but not in the correct location. Please see my added screenshot for the result:[image: Incorrect render when using document.getElementById()]

At this point I'm stuck. I dont know how I can achieve that the canvas is rendered in the correct div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching Google for a while longer, I found a solution.

The `onRender: function() { }` "gets triggered when the View's DOM subtree is prepared for insertion into the DOM but before those elements are viewable", according to [this webiste.](http://averycodes.com/blog/proper-and-improper-uses-of-marionettes-onshow-and-onrender/)

after changing `onRender` to `onShow` in my javascript file, the canvas element is rendered in the correct location.